# Daily delete X oldest cached files (no matter how many days old) from directory (cron)

Tags: file, cron, server

For my personal website (file based cms, php, shared host, ssh access ok), I'm using a cache system which basically saves every served page. I use a single dedicated directory /htmlcache for that purpose, now stocking about 60k small files.
It's working fine.

Now what I need is an easy solution to delete X oldest files (since creation time) on daily or weekly basis (say : 100 oldest files daily or 700 weekly, to be adapted to the rhythm I like).

A lot of informations to be found for how to delete files older than X days, but not so much for how to to delete X oldest files.

Why I very strongly prefer to automatically delete X oldest files each day rather than X days aged files each day is because a lot of cached files have been created in a few days and I want something smooth and linear.

I guess one has to go in the cache directory, sort files by date, select X files and delete them. Well. I know nothing about cron and almost nothing about unix command and I wish a guide might help me for the commands and the how to to use it.

Because the directory is quite large (60k files, growing up to 100k maximum I guess), I wish the solution takes care of the server (for the list and sort process) (I dont mind to delete oldest files daily : weekly basis is fine as well).

There are no subdirectories in my cache directory an cached files are named this way :

```
Foo.Bar.htlm
MyGroup.MyOtherWords.html
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end, if I'm not mistaken, the way it works for me (should be used with some automation tool) is : connect with ssh, and run this command for deleting 1000 oldest files in the current directory :

`ls -1tr | head -1000 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f`

Credit to [pmcjury](https://gist.github.com/pmcjury/8f4de88c0eb6fbfa9aaa)